# How to enable the CodeDeploy Agent on Amazon Linux 2?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-code-deploy

Amazon Linux 2 already comes with `cfn-init` and other AWS integrated tools, but the [CodeDeploy docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/codedeploy-agent.html) doesn't mention Amazon Linux 2 and running any service commands respond something similar to:

```
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl start codedeploy-agent.service
Failed to start codedeploy-agent.service: Unit not found.
```

How can I enable the CodeDeploy agent, preferably using `cfn-init`?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
sudo yum update
sudo yum install ruby
sudo yum install wget
wget https://aws-codedeploy-us-east-1.s3.amazonaws.com/latest/install
chmod +x ./install
sudo ./install auto
```

The above worked, though it's not integrated to `cfn-init` so I'm still looking for a better answer.

EDIT: Working configSet for `cfn-init`

```
    cdagent:
      packages:
        yum:
          ruby: []
          wget: []
      commands:
        install:
          command: !Sub |
            wget https://aws-codedeploy-${AWS::Region}.s3.amazonaws.com/latest/install
            chmod +x ./install
            ./install auto
```

Comment: These instructions are detailed in the AWS docs here, for people who want more information: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/codedeploy-agent-operations-install-linux.html